# How do I know the positional value of a character in a string with respect to that of the English alphabets?

Tags: c++, ascii

For example if I have something like :

```
word="Bag"
```

I need output as:

B-2
a-1
g-7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a more portable solution:

There are only 26 letters to consider, thus your question is easily answerable by simply providing a lookup table.  There is no need to call functions such as `tolower`, or to assume that letters are contiguous in the collating sequence (as EBCDIC does not follow this pattern):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

int main()
{
   // Create the lookup table -- this could have been done in many ways,
   // such as a static table of characters to values, but I chose a simple
   // literal string and build the table at runtime.

   const char *alpha = "aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ";
   std::unordered_map<char, int> cMap;
   for (int i = 0; i < 52; ++i)
       cMap[alpha[i]] = i / 2;  // Note there are two characters per character value, 
                                // the lower and the upper case version of the character

   // Test
   std::string test = "Bag";
   for ( auto& c : test)
      std::cout << c << '-' << cMap[c]+1 << ' ';
   std::cout << '\n';

   test = "Buy";
   for ( auto& c : test)
      std::cout << c << '-' << cMap[c]+1 << ' ';
   std::cout << '\n';

   test = "Elephant";
   for ( auto& c : test)
      std::cout << c << '-' << cMap[c]+1 << ' ';
}
```

Output:

```
B-2 a-1 g-7 
B-2 u-21 y-25 
E-5 l-12 e-5 p-16 h-8 a-1 n-14 t-20
```

Comment: interesting! can you please advise something what I can read to have a better idea when exactly a character is translated into its code (compile time vs run-time), which encoding is used? I though c/c++ just follows ASCII standard and compilers stick to it, but as it turned out it's not true

Comment: C++ can't follow strictly ASCII, since there are non-ASCII computers (mainly mainframes) that have C++ compilers.  Thus true cross-platform code cannot assume ASCII encoding, for example, encryption libraries, cryptography libraries, compression libraries, etc.

Comment: Thanks, but it's still a bit hard. Probably I need better understanding of some low level stuff, but if roughly speaking (sorry if I'm talking nonsense, just want to bound this in my head) a compiler translates characters into their codes using some encoding. But how does it decide which encoding to use - ASCII or EBCDIC or even something else? What does it depend on - OS, CPU? Or maybe the whole process is very different from how I understand it?

Comment: Ask yourself "how do functions such as `isalpha` work without errors?".  The writers of that function must know beforehand what system the compiler will be running on.  For the ASCII systems, maybe the writers did this:  `if (ch >= 'a' && ch <='z'  || ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')`, but in the EBCDIC version of the compiler, they did something else.  Regardless of the system, `isalpha` is guaranteed to give the correct answer, which is why the `if` statement I mentioned is *not* the way for end-user code to determine if a character is alphabetic or not.  A user program must always use `isalpha`.

Comment: I see now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

```
for (char ch: word) {
    cout << ch << "-" << (tolower(ch) - 'a' + 1) << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope the below code snippet helps :

```
char c = 'g';  //your character here

int position = 1 + (tolower(c))-'a': //ensure that character is in lowercase and find its position relative to 'a'
```

Comment: Glad to help. 

Comment: It works in ASCII, but C++ actually provides no guarantees that the letters are organised like this. A lookup table is a more portable way to do this.

Comment: @john can you elaborate. I didn't exactly get you. For me this works in every case I have encountered.

Comment: @Abhishek It only works because the letters have consecutive values, so in ASCII (for instance) a=97, b=98, c=99 etc. But in [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) you have h=136, i=137, j=145. So this formula wouldn't work if you were using a computer that used EBCDIC. It's not very common to find computers using EBCDIC but they still exist.

Comment: @john This achieves the desired result. And any computer would probably have alphabet in the same order/sequence. So it should work almost everywhere. The lookup table idea also works, but is just more tedious and wouldn't be of much use without having a specific need which can't be achieved using formula I mentioned.

Comment: @Abhishek Almost everywhere is correct. But if you want it to work anywhere at all a lookup table is better.

Comment: @Abhishek -- FYI -- If you were working on a library that has to work across platforms, your solution would be rejected because it makes assumption about alphabetic characters always being contiguous.  AFAIK, the only set of characters that are guaranteed to be contiguous are the digit characters.